# Is there a way for a laser to work across a range of colors?

Tags: laser

For lasers used for free space / mirror steered / diffuse beam communications or LIDAR scanning, would there be some way for a single laser to be able to selectively transmit across a range of colors, to a receiver that can similarly distinguish between colors?

This would be similar in operating principle to a radio transmitter that can adjust its transmitting frequency up or down across the radio spectrum, to a radio receiver that can distinguish what frequency it is receiving.

Comment: As I recall, dye lasers are tunable within a range of frequencies. This might be a better question for physics.SE though, I think?

Comment: What do you mean by tunable? All lasers are tunable to some extent. Across a wide range of wavelengths? not really unless you get super expensive.

Comment: I don't think you can tune photodiodes at all...the only method I have heard of is using multiple photodiodes or rotating different filters in front of them.

Comment: You can spectrally disperse the light with a prism or grating and use an array of spatially separated photodiodes - a spectrometer.

Answer (score 1):

Through the magic of nonlinear optics you can buy a super supercontinuum laser which outputs light in a very broad spectrum, typically 400 nm to 1,700 nm.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercontinuum

[image]

A small wavelength band may be selected with an [acousto-optic modulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acousto-optic_modulator)

See one in action tuning over the wavelength band:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7_E_sOOl9U

Comment: It appears to me that what you are describing is spectral broadening, with no easy way of **tuning** the wavelength. If so, then you have missed the point of the question.

Comment: I'd agree, though I can see how with a bit of mechanics, one could *select* a color

Comment: The usual method is to use an acousto-optic modulator.

Answer (score 0):

There's very different kinds of lasers, and while there's tunable lasers, these really don't belong in the category of things you mount on a LIDAR scanner, at all.

So, no, no adjustable lasers themselves.

You can, however, *frequencymix* lasers with laser, and lasers with RF signals, and do all kinds of crazy photonic things. But: either that will be very discrete (mixing laser with laser: you can only get discrete lasers) or far below what you'd call "a range of colors": If you use a really high-frequency (e.g. 60 GHz) RF signal to modulate a red laser (say at 400.000 THz), then the resulting color will still be exactly as you can optically determine without mixing coherently with the original laser: red, the exact same red as before (now at 400.060 THz, congrats).

Comment: I have a tunable argon laser. (And a nice HeNe.) It's not that big. But I haven't done anything with LIDAR, so I'm ignorant. I wish the OP wrote more about why there is a need for a "range of colors" and why "color" was chosen instead of "wavelength." Oh, well. I may learn something in this discussion.

Comment: Nice :) What'd you use that laser for?

Comment: @jonk It's the only way to get your weapons to bypass enemy shields.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hehe. Mostly for show (and it does appear to work for sky writing, for example.) It's a \$25\:\text{mW}\$ laser that I got from Optical Data, Inc when they were selling old equipment. I got it really cheap. How could I turn it down? (They also were selling an HPLC, but the asking price, while cheap, was high enough that I could not justify it as a "toy" for my home. (Yes, I buy toys!!! Lots of toys!) Luckily, I have a large house and auxillary buildings and a large property (about 5 hectares.)

Comment: @jonk you clearly did something right there. Nice!